# Exception on SaveChanges through DataService

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf-data-services

I made an aplication in WPF that is suppose to get the data on my form and save it to a database (through a data service). If I do this on my machine and in the server that is hosted the service all works fine. But if I do in a different machine I get DataServiceRequestException. I'm guessing is something with the config but the exception is not very acurate.

Is there a way to have more information from there?

I already have:

```
        config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
```

and

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
```

On my service side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could leverage **IErrorHandler** interface provide by service model to fetch all the exception coming in service operation. Below is the code and find the appropriate comments regarding how to debug:

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class YourService : IErrorHandler
{
    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
        //Put the break point and monitor the exception.
        //or put some log in Handle error method.
    }

    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        //log the exception in this method as it run on separate thread.
        return true;
    }
}
```

I hope this answer your question.